# Button Clicked Animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I want to create an animation where when the user clicks on the button it will animate how it is pressed. When the base Start was click it will animate to right start. I tried Sprite swap but both sprites have different height and is it possible to animate and change size to make it look it was pressed. Thanks!

[image: As you can see the Left start is the base and the right start is the animation after]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do button animation by using code or animation.
If you want to do by using code you can change the sprite using code but that time it is good to keep the size same of your two sprite.

But in animation you can do lot.
[image: button property]

In button change the transition mood to animation you will get 4 state Normal,Highlighted,Pressed and Disabled with trigger name beside.
[image: Animator]
Now create a animation for that button as you wish and set the trigger on that animator .Unity will automatically take care your state .

Comment: how to open that tab??

Comment: Go to windows and select animator and open the animator window.